# How to read Phone number in iOS 10.1.1 - Objective C/Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, callkit

I have saw so many Questions regarding this on SO. All answers say that it is not possible. `Apple` doesn't allow to do so.

I am using `iPhone 6s` running on `iOS 10.1.1`

Yesterday I purchased new Sim Card.Just after inserting my new SIM when I opened `WhatsApp`. I get a Screen which says:

```
   `Your number has been changed. Do you want to use new number`
```

**How does whatsapp able to do so?**

Secondly I installed `Airtel` App. When I opened the app. It automatically fetched my phone number And Displayed to me.

How these apps are able to read phone number.

Is apple added new methods in `iOS 10` or they are using some other logic to do so.

Answer (score 1):

There is an observer `subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier`

as per the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coretelephony/cttelephonynetworkinfo/1616898-subscribercellularproviderdidupd)

> A block object that is dispatched on the default priority global
>   dispatch queue when the user’s cellular provider information changes.
>   This occurs, for example, if a user swaps the device’s SIM card with
>   one from another provider, while your application is running.
>
> To handle changes in cellular service provider information, define a
>   block in your application and assign it to this property. The block
>   must be implemented to support being called from any context.

That just notifies you that your sim has been changed.

Regarding your second question you can get the number from contact app using `Contacts.framework`

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes in privacy in ios 10. A new key you have to add into plist file if you want to access contacts database in your app.

`<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) want use you contacts</string>`

Comment: how this leads to get Phone number. As There i can only get other contact details

Comment: I think @Rajat is correct. They used `subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier` to get your phone number and matched with existing whatsapp database.

Comment: @Poles I have never mentioned that from `subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier` you will be able to get phone number, that is just an observer which will fire when you change your cellular provider